# HIVE - how to handle multiple quoteChar in serde

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have source file CSV and data looks like below

> "201814    ","39","0598824","YELLOW JACKET TRAP W","PIEGE
>   GUEP.JAU,OUEST","ACT","7/20/2016","C/E
>   ","05","ST","N","15","2484","985.39999999999998","43.66","3762.36","53.05","
>   ","N","","5.83","7.9900",".0000",".0000","3.82","3.8181","7162","STERLING
>   INTN'L","D","12","YJTD-DB12-W-","12","32","0","0","0",**"\"**,"3.68","0","","
>   ","","","","          ",""

to load the data i am using the below create statement with serde

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = "|",
   "quoteChar"     = '\"',
   "escapeChar"    = '\\')
```

Issue is after "\" what ever data is present in file is coming as NULL

Could you please let me know how to handle this?

my complete DDL used

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE
    excess_inventory
    (
        whole_record string,
        yyyyww string,
        excess_wks_num string,
        product_num string,
        eng_desc string,
        fr_desc string,
        status string,
        corp_status_change_date string,
        whse_region string,
        whse_id string,
        channel_cd string,
        eap_ind string,
        fwos string,
        non_alloc_qty string,
        excess_qty string,
        excess_cube string,
        excess_inventory_dollars string,
        monthly_storage_cost string,
        deal_600 string,
        go_ind string,
        next_5_deals string,
        reg_adlr string,
        reg_retail string,
        r52_best_promo_adlr string,
        r52_best_promo_retail string,
        landed_cost string,
        corp_cost string,
        vendor_num string,
        vendor_nm string,
        vendor_origin string,
        vendor_moq string,
        vendor_part_num string,
        vendor_lead_tm string,
        total_lead_tm string,
        ingate_qty string,
        on_order_qty string,
        dealer_restriction_cd string,
        quote_cost string,
        casting_charge string,
        action_cd string,
        action_yyyyww string,
        action_qty string,
        sugg_adlr string,
        comments string,
        create_yyyyww string,
        user_nm string,
    batch_ts timestamp
) 
PARTITIONED BY (partition_batch_ts bigint)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = "|",
   "quoteChar"     = '\"',
   "escapeChar"    = '\\') 
 STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION
'db/excess_inventory/table'
TBLPROPERTIES('skip.header.line.count'='1','serialization.null.format'='');
```

also let me know "separatorChar" = "|", is used to say data as to be saved in HDFS as pipe seperator or we have to specify the delimiter in the source file?

Comment: ,"\","3.68","0",""," ","","",""," ",""    after slash what ever data is there its not getting loading

Comment: Your separator seems to be a `,`?

Comment: "separatorChar" = "|"   if i make it to "separatorChar" = "," all the columns data is coming to single column